# How do I check that all values in a dictionary with variable levels of nesting are truthy or falsey?

Tags: python, python-2.7

There are various API endpoints that I call that return response objects of varying complexities and I need to parse through an unknown level of nested data structures of either lists and/or dictionaries.

For example, if I get back a response and convert the json to a dictionary here:

```
response = {
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2",
   "key3":"value3",
   "key4":[
      "item1",
      "item2"
   ],
   "key5":"value4",
   "key6":"value5",
   "key7":{
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":"value3",
      "key4":"value4",
      "key5":"value5",
      "key6":"value6"
   },
   "key8":"value6"
}
```

My method below will work, since its only dealing with lists or dictionaries one level deep in nesting:

```
def check_values(payload):

    values = []

    for value in payload.values():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                values.append(bool(item))
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            for nested_value in value.values():
                values.append(bool(nested_value))
        else:
            values.append(bool(value))

    if all(values):
        return True
    return False

print(check_values(response))
```

However, if I have something like this, my method above wouldn't work:

```
response = {
   "key1": {"foobar" : ["a", None, {"xyz": 123}]},
   "key2":"value2",
   "key3":"value3",
   "key4":[
      [4, 5, 6],
      [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[["hi"]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
   ],
   "key5":"value4",
   "key6":"value5",
   "key7":{
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":"value3",
      "key4":"value4",
      "key5":"value5",
      "key6":"value6"
   },
   "key8":"value6"
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. =)

Comment: "key4":[
      [4, 5, 6],
      [4] # try this
   ], because list was empty maybe thats why you were getting False ** bool([ ])
False**

Comment: @Tanmayjain, that was on purpose and to show the shortcomings of my method. Even if there was not an empty list, the method should still return False, because None is a item inside a nested list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f_response = {
   'val0':[1,2,3,[True],[42]],
   'val1':{}, # assuming {} ,[] are Falsey values bool({}) False
   'val2':['x'],
   'val3':[[[False]]]
}

t_response = {
    'val0':[1,2,3,[True],[42]],
   'val1':{1:[43]}, 
   'val2':['x'],
   'val3':[[[True,[True]]]]   
    }

response = {
   "key1": {"foobar" : ["a", None, {"xyz": 123}]},
   "key2":"value2",
   "key3":"value3",
   "key4":[
      [4, 5, 6],
      []
   ],
   "key5":"value4",
   "key6":"value5",
   "key7":{
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",
      "key3":"value3",
      "key4":"value4",
      "key5":"value5",
      "key6":"value6"
   },
   "key8":"value6"
}

def check_values(payload):

    if isinstance(payload, dict): 
        if payload != {}:
            for value in payload.values():
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    if not check_values(value):
                        return False
                elif isinstance(value, dict):
                    if not check_values(value):
                        return False
                else:
                    if not bool(value):
                        return False
        else:
           return False

    elif isinstance(payload, list):
        if payload != []:
            for value in payload:
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    if not check_values(value):
                        return False
                elif isinstance(value, dict):
                    if not check_values(value):
                        return False
                else:
                    if not bool(value):
                        return False
        else:
            return False

    return True

print(check_values(f_response)) #False

print(check_values(t_response)) #True

print(check_values(response)) #False
```

Comment: Ahhh...thanks! This solution works for me and is more elegant.

Comment: @JeffreyLee please check the changes that I have made, before it was giving wrong output in some cases.

Comment: Yep it looks like I spoke too soon, I tried the following and it doesn't work: `response = {
    "key1": {"foobar": ["a", "b", {"xyz": 123}]},
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": [
        [4, 5, 6],
        [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[["hi"]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
    ],
    "key5": "value4",
    "key6": ["value5", [[[True, [False]]]]],
    "key7": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3",
        "key4": "value4",
        "key5": "value5",
        "key6": "value6"
    },
    "key8": ["value6", {"one": 1}, "should work now"]
}`

Comment: @JeffreyLee its giving False as an output so its working correctly right ?

Comment: Nope, because I have the string "hi"  and not an empty string in that ridiculously nested group of lists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178177/discussion-between-jeffrey-lee-and-tanmay-jain).